# How to build a map that highlights only one state?

Tags: cartography, carto, visualisation, maps

I'm a journalist working on maps of several Alaska databases. I'm learning as I go and have a question that's probably very basic, but very important for my projects:

Using CartoDB, how can I create a map that displays only Alaska? (ie not the rest of the US or other countries)

A simple step-by-step answer to this would be immensely helpful!

Answer (score 2):

When you are writing your SQL query after importing the USA dataset (as Javier referenced above), be sure to select 1) "the_geom", 2) "the_geom_webmercator", and 3) "cartodb_id". See my code underneath:

```
SELECT ne_50m_admin_1_states.the_geom, ne_50m_admin_1_states.the_geom_webmercator, ne_50m_admin_1_states.cartodb_id FROM ne_50m_admin_1_states WHERE ne_50m_admin_1_states.name = 'Alaska'
```

For more on projections in CartoDB, please see: http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/projections.html

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to import a USA states dataset where it is placed in the common data section (http://{{ yourusername }}.cartodb.com/dashboard/common_data/Administrative%20regions). Then, you can remove all the polygons or states you don't need and only leave Alaska. Hope it helps you!

Cheers,
Javier Á.